# How to record local3 with all severity levels to a file using system logger?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syslog, rsyslog, logger

I'm using a VM. Ubuntu Linux.

What I'm trying to do is use System logger to record the `local3` facility with all severity levels to a file `/var/log/local3.log`

I'm confused as to what the process is. Am I just supposed to edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` with something along the lines of:

```
local3.*      /var/log/local3.log
```

or do I use the `logger` command? Or both?

I also want to add a `logrotate` afterwards so that it rotates weekly, keeping 8 weeks worth of log files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file, add/create your custom audits into `/etc/rsyslog.d/30-custom_audits.conf` with the following line:

```
local3.*      -/var/log/local3.log
```

then to enable rotation on `/var/log/local3.log`, add *filepath* in your `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` configuration as well.

and restart the `rsyslog` service if you are using *systemd*:

```
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

else restart with:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```